# How to generate numpy arrays of different sizes (e.g. objects) but then apply mathematical operations on them

Tags: python, numpy

I am attempting to do a minimization via sum of squares, but my global minimization I am doing has arrays of different sizes. I am trying to minimize using all data sets, even though they are different sizes.

I.E.

```
data_1=[[1,2],[2,3]]
data_2=[[3,4],[5,6],[6,7]]
model_1=[[1,1],[2,2]]
model_2=[[3,3],[5,5],[6,6]]
```

Now the data/model are the same size, so doing

```
sum((data_1-model_1)**2)
```

works. The issue is I'm trying to combine all the data and all the models for a global fit.

```
total_data=[[[1,2],[2,3]],[[3,4],[5,6],[6,7]]]
total_model=[[[1,1],[2,2]],[[3,3],[5,5],[6,6]]]
```

Now you can make lists of lists like this, but I'd like to make a numpy array so that I can then do mathematical operations such as

```
np.sum((total_data-total_model)**2)
```

You can make numpy objects, but they are handled as lists, and as such mathematical numpy operations do not apply to list objects.

Any advice for how to do this would be greatly appreciated! I'm just trying to consolidate my data and do a global fit rather than making multiple nested loops and treating each one individually.

Answer (score 0):

The subtractions of the matrices of different sizes are different operations, there is no way around that. You can employ various kinds of numpy and Python magic to make it seem like one operation, but at the end of the day, something like

```py
data_list = [...]  # List of numpy arrays
model_list = [...]  # same, with corresponding sizes

error = 0
for data, model in zip(data_list, model_list):
   error += np.sum((data-model)**2)
```

will be the most obvious and clear.

If this ever becomes a performance bottleneck, you could employ [numba](https://numba.pydata.org/).

Answer (score 0):

We can do some math on object dtype arrays, but not everything.  And that math, when it works, is done at list-comprehension speeds, not at the compiled speeds for numeric dtypes.

Make lists of arrays:

```
In [20]: datalist= [np.array(data_1),np.array(data_2)]
    ...: modlist = [np.array(model_1),np.array(model_2)]
```

Then the straightforward application of your calculation to these pairs:

```
In [21]: [np.sum((data-model)**2) for data, model in zip(datalist, modlist)]
Out[21]: [2, 3]
```

Now try making object dtype arrays from those lists:

```
In [22]: A=np.array(datalist,object); B=np.array(modlist,object)    
In [23]: A
Out[23]: 
array([array([[1, 2],
              [2, 3]]), 
       array([[3, 4],
              [5, 6],
              [6, 7]])], dtype=object)
```

Notice how this is different from making an array from your list of lists:

```
In [24]: np.array(total_data,object)
Out[24]: 
array([list([[1, 2], [2, 3]]), list([[3, 4], [5, 6], [6, 7]])],
      dtype=object)
```

Operators like +/* generally work with object dtype lists, provided the elements implement them as well:

```
In [25]: C=(A-B)**2    
In [26]: C
Out[26]: 
array([array([[0, 1],
              [0, 1]]), array([[0, 1],
                               [0, 1],
                               [0, 1]])], dtype=object)
```

Arrays of lists can't do this, because lists don't implement most operators.

And we can't apply the `sum` function to that array:

```
In [27]: np.sum(C)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[27], line 1
----> 1 np.sum(C)

File <__array_function__ internals>:200, in sum(*args, **kwargs)

File ~\miniconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\fromnumeric.py:2324, in sum(a, axis, dtype, out, keepdims, initial, where)
   2321         return out
   2322     return res
-> 2324 return _wrapreduction(a, np.add, 'sum', axis, dtype, out, keepdims=keepdims,
   2325                       initial=initial, where=where)

File ~\miniconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\fromnumeric.py:86, in _wrapreduction(obj, ufunc, method, axis, dtype, out, **kwargs)
     83         else:
     84             return reduction(axis=axis, out=out, **passkwargs)
---> 86 return ufunc.reduce(obj, axis, dtype, out, **passkwargs)

ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (2,2) (3,2)
```

Same is true for functions like `log` or `sin`.

But we can resort to the explicit list comprehension:

```
In [28]: [np.sum(x) for x in C]
Out[28]: [2, 3]
```